# "hello world" string literal can be assigned to char * type?

Tags: c++, string, constants

```
char* foo = "fpp"; //compile in vs 2010 with no problem
```

I though string literal is const char* type.
And const type cannot be assigned to non-const type.
So I expect the code above to fail or am I missing something?

Edit: Sorry guys, I totally forgotten that compiler throws warning too.
I was looking at error list all this time.
I'm forget to check that.

Edit2: I set my project Warning Level to EnableAllWarnings (/Wall) and there's no warning about this.
So my question is still valid.

Comment: Just to be sure (I see C++ tag) C or C++ program?

Comment: I believe it would throw only warning if any, if you assign char*=const char*...

Comment: can you try writing a minimal code, compile to .o & take objdump of the .o file; just to see if this fpp resides in RO memory, or in RAM.

Comment: gcc just gives warning not error: http://liveworkspace.org/code/b7aea430807569a60acfaa1e6276b03e - did you check for warnings in VS2010?

Comment: I can only guess - but I think it's for compatibility reasons with C-APIs. The is actually absolutely necessary since writing to foo[1] (e.g. foo[1]='l';) fails with an access violation. And VS2010 doesn't even give a warning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand it, in C, before `const` was added, this was the way to assign a string to a pointer.

In C++ this is *deprecated* behavior, but still allowed to keep backwards compatibility. So don't use it.

In fact, I believe in C++11 it's completely invalid.

Comment: okay i get it.C++ is backward compatible with C and const is only added in C++.This made sense.

Answer (score 6):

C++03 deprecates<sup>[Ref 1]</sup> use of string literal without the `const` keyword.

<sup>[Ref 1]</sup>**C++03 Standard: §4.2/2**

> A string literal (2.13.4) that is not a wide string literal can be converted to an rvalue of type “pointer to char”; a wide string literal can be converted to an rvalue of type “pointer to wchar_t”. In either case, the result is a pointer to the first element of the array. This conversion is considered only when there is an explicit appropriate pointer target type, and not when there is a general need to convert from an lvalue to an rvalue. [**Note: this conversion is deprecated**. See Annex D. ] For the purpose of ranking in overload resolution (13.3.3.1.1), this conversion is considered an array-to-pointer conversion followed by a qualification conversion (4.4). [Example: "abc" is converted to “pointer to const char” as an array-to-pointer conversion, and then to “pointer to char” as a qualification conversion. ]

C++11 simply removes the above quotation which implies that it is illegal code in C++11.

Prior to C++03, C++ derived its declaration of string literal without the `const` keyword, Note that the same is perfectly valid in C.

Answer (score 2):

Not quite. A string literal is assignable to a `char*` type. A string literal should never be modified.

This strange situation is for backwards compatibility with programs before `const` existed.

Comment: Not sure why this got a down-vote as I believe it is correct?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, ok I'll amend my answer.

Comment: @Luchian: thanks - this is why down-votes without explanation are unhelpful.

Comment: @PaulR I agree. 99% of the time I do leave a comment, but initially the answer was "Not quite. A string literal is a char* type."... A comment would have been redundant in this case.

Answer (score 1):

`gcc -std=c++0x` warns about this:

> a.cpp:5:14: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

So, this is still allowed, but deprecated, because literal strings are const.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a const type. Const keyword is a so called type qualifier. It can be applied to any pointer type and just means that the value pointed at by the pointer should not be modified.

You could also apply the const qualifier to the pointer reference itself this way:

```
char* const p ="aaa";
```

This will protect the pointer variable from pointing to another string.

Answer (score 1):

There's a special implicit conversion to support this, since it was a common idiom in legacy code (often written before `const` existed).  The type of your string literal is `char const[]`, and you should only use it as such.  A good compiler will warn at the above, since the conversion was deprecated from the moment it was introduced.

Note that this is different from C, where the type of a string literal is `char[]` (but trying to modify it is still undefined behavior).

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about C strings, which are actually vector of char. In C++, the class `std::string` is used, as well as a constant string is created as `const std::string`.

Anyway, compilers reserve a piece of memory in the future program in order to store the literal strings that show up in the source code. This part of the memory is considered read-only, so you shoud point to it with a `const char *`. It size is exactly the size of the string plus one extra position for the trailing zero, marking the end of the string.

Compilers need to keep backwards compatibility, so they still accept literals to be pointed by `char *`. However, this is misleading, since you are not supposed to be able to modify that memory which could be stored in ROM in an embedded system.

In my system, I use clang:

```
$ clang --version
Ubuntu clang version 3.0-6ubuntu3 (tags/RELEASE_30/final) (based on LLVM 3.0)
Target: i386-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
```

In the clang C compiler, this code compiles without errors:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char * str = "Hello, World!";

    printf( "%s", str );

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

However, the very same code (with minor modifications, such as the header's names) throws the following warning when compiled as a C++ program:

```
kk.cpp:6:15: warning: conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-writable-strings]
        char * str = "Hello, World!";
                     ^
1 warning generated.
```

Hope this helps.