# Why does modifying a string literal cause a segmentation fault?

Tags: c

Why does modifying a pre-initialized string literal cause a segmentation fault? For example:

```
char *str = "Hello world";
str[0] = 'h';
```

When you initialize `str` to that string value, doesn't the compiler automatically allocate memory for that string constant, assign its starting location to `str` and free it upon program exit?

Comment: The problem is that you shouldn't assign a string literal to a `char *`, it's deprecated, and your compiler should have generated a warning. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13248399/hello-world-string-literal-can-be-assigned-to-char-type

Comment: if you want to read a bit more about this I'd take a look at https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/STR30-C.+Do+not+attempt+to+modify+string+literals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is in a read only section of the process's address space because the string literal is a constant. (the `str` variable is not in read only space but it should be made to point to a valid writable location before you can use it the way you do.)