# C weird pointer behaviour SIGSEGV in string

Tags: c++, c, segmentation-fault

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
char * inplace_rev(char * s){
    int n=strlen(s);
    int i=0;
    char aux,aux2;
    while(i<=n/2){
        aux=s[n-i-1];
        aux2=s[i];
        s[i]=aux;
        s[n-i-1]=aux2;
        i++;
    }
    return s;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("%d\n",sizeof(int));
    char *s=(char *)malloc(100);
    s="abcdef";
    printf("%s",s);
    printf("%s\n%s",s,inplace_rev(s));
    return 0;
}
```

The segmentation fault happens at the first iteration of the while structure in method "inplace rev". More specifically, at

```
s[i]=aux;
```

I used two aux variables to emphasize the segmentation fault.
Basically, I'm trying to reverse a string in place.
Thanks in advance !
It

Comment: You cannot assign a string liike that in C. You need to use strcpy(s, "abcdef");

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19600526/why-does-modifying-a-string-literal-cause-a-segmentation-fault